# How do I return the contents of a cell that I have the address for (e.g. "A2")?

Tags: excel

I have cell addresses in one worksheet formatted as text strings (e.g. "A1", "B22", "F332") and I'd like to return the contents of those particular cell addresses from another worksheet. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *INDIRECT()*:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet3!" & A1)
```

[image]

This gets the contents of cell **A1** from *Sheet3*.

*If your sheetname includes blanks, encapsulate it in single quotes.*

Comment: Thanks! Solved my issue.